# Symfony 2 - Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement Country->State->City with one to many relation in symfony 2. I just started using symfony, I found some links on this but could not get it working as those were for older version of symfony.

I have generated 3 entities as Country, State and City.

Note : City is not directly has relation with Country but indirectly via State.

I generated CRUD for all these entities.

State and country works great, but I need to select country then state and enter city on city creation form.

I am following tutorial from symfony cookbook from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

My CityType looks as follows.

```
namespace Aceonics\SystemBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

use Aceonics\SystemBundle\Entity\Country;
use Aceonics\SystemBundle\Entity\State;

class CityType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                'class'         => 'AceonicsSystemBundle:Country',
                'property'      => 'name',
                    //This line is added as City and Country do not have direct relation
                'mapped'        => false, 
                'empty_value'   => 'Choose an option'
            ))
            ->add('name')
        ;   

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
            $states = null === $country ? array() : $country->getStates();

            $form->add('state', 'entity', array(
                'class'       => 'AceonicsSystemBundle:State',
                'choices'     => $states,
                'empty_value' => 'Choose an option'
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();

                //Error Occurs here.
                //As per tutorial it should be $data->getCountry()
                //But as I do not have direct relation I have used $data->getState()->getCountry
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getState()->getCountry());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
            }
        ); 
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Aceonics\SystemBundle\Entity\City'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'aceonics_systembundle_city';
    }
}
```

If I use `$data->getCountry()` then I get following error:

```
Attempted to call method "getCountry" on class "Aceonics\SystemBundle\Entity\City" in E:\localhost\Aceonics_Apps\PHP_Frameworks\symfony\src\Aceonics\SystemBundle\Form\CityType.php line 49
```

If I use `$data->getState()->getCountry()` then I get following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getCountry() on a non-object in E:\localhost\Aceonics_Apps\PHP_Frameworks\symfony\src\Aceonics\SystemBundle\Form\CityType.php line 49
```

I have tried to put this into if statement of isInstance but it didn't help.

Please help me in understanding this and solving the problem.

Comment: Follow [this tutorial](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/03/19/dynamic-form-modification-in-symfony2/) it is perfect and well written.

Comment: Thank You @StivenLlupa Let me read it.

Comment: Here is another very good tutorial - http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/